# How to rotate a parent object so that the child that the user clicked on is now perpendicular to the player

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector

So I have a car object and basically the player will select a part on it and be able to look at the description and other things. What I currently want to do is when the user clicks on one of these parts that the car rotates so that the part is looking at the player so to speak. My problem is I am terrible with Vector math lol. I have a script that basically gets the child(part) object, the parent(car) object, and the player/camera object when ever the user clicks on a part. I feel as though my math is wrong here but I just can't figure it out. What I am doing in the script below is making the positions into two dimensions because I only want to rotate on the y axis of the parent object.

```
Vector3 hitObjPos = new Vector3(hitObject.transform.position.x, 0, hitObject.transform.position.z);
Vector3 baseObjPos = new Vector3(baseObj.transform.position.x, 0, baseObj.transform.position.z);
Vector3 playerPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, transform.position.z);

Vector3 childHeading = hitObjPos - baseObjPos;
Vector3 playerHeading = playerPos - baseObjPos;

float angle = Vector3.Angle(childHeading, playerHeading);

if(angle > 75 || angle < -75)
    baseObj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, baseObj.transform.eulerAngles.y+ angle, 0);
```

Here is a picture of my thought process.

[image: Example1]

**My problem is that this code works for one half of the object, but the other half, it rotates in the opposite direction**. As seen below:

[image: Example2]

**Edit:**
After doing some more testing, I realized that the `angle` that is being output is positive regardless of where it is on the object. Which I feel like makes this question a whole lot easier. **How can I determine what direction my rotation needs to be, positive or negative?**

Comment: This is not a trivial problem. You're probably going to have to calculate the rotations for each object yourself and store them in a script.

Comment: Okay, well how would you do it for just two objects, i.e. one parent and one child? I guess my problem is grasping the overall concept of how to calculate the necessary rotation to give to the parent.

Comment: The simplest case would just involve making the vector `child.position - parent.position` be parallel to `parent.position - camera.position`, but for complex objects (like a car) that may not always work (e.g. the steering wheel is inside the car, but forward of its center)